Can I say "the book is upside-down" when it lies flat on a table?
My 2-year-old son holds his book the wrong way as explained below.
I think "the book is upside-down" looks like this when it is held vertically.
 (source)
However, say the book is lying flat on the table and when you look at the book, the letter A does not have the same direction with your eyes (I don't know how to say it but it looks like this):

Can I say "the book is upside-down, please turn it right-side-up" in this situation?
Can I say "the book is upside-down" when it lies flat on a table?
Note: searching for "book is upside down horizontally", I often see this type of image
 (source)

Please expend more effort describing the speech context and less effort depicting the physical world with makeshift sketches.  Who would you be saying this to, and why?  There's only one head at the table.  Is that person alone?

The book is spine up on the table.

You already seem to know that it's ambiguous. So what else do you want to know?  We can tell you how to express yourself more clearly but I'm guessing you don't actually want that?

Situations when we can say, "The book is upside down":

Picture 1: The book is being held upside down.
Picture 2: The book is lying upside down on the table.

In summary, a book is "upside down" when its text is inverted relative to the reader's gaze, making it difficult to read. This applies whether the book is held vertically or lying flat.

Picture 3: The book is open and lying face down, with its pages spread out. Since the cover's orientation is correct, it is not typically described as "upside down."
Instead, it is more accurate to say,
"The book is lying open, face down."


+1 for the (open) book is opened "face down"*

The pages are not spread out. The book is open, spine up.

If we are talking to a child who knows when a book is not oriented properly for reading, we can say

Turn the book around so you can read it.

The book is not upside down, but the words are.

You can't read the book when the words are upside down.

But some children are unusual. When my son was being evaluated for pre-school, the teacher, sitting opposite him at a little table, centered a sheet of paper very neatly between them on the table,  like it was a special ritual, handed him a pencil, and said:

Could you write your name for me on this piece of paper?

He wrote it upside down and backwards, so she could read it without having to turn the paper around.

I was a little like your son, but my father found it disturbing, rather than a source of pride, as you clearly do.

@MichaelHarvey Proud that he could transpose things spatially like that at age three, but at the same time thinking that he had made it much harder for himself than it needed to be.

@TimR This is quite extraordinary. Although (with apologies) this conversation is not relevant to English learning, has your son subsequently demonstrated this ability again?>

made it much harder for himself than it needed to be - that was (and is) me all over!

@RonaldSole Nothing out of the ordinary, other than having preternatural hand-eye coordination. It's like being in The Matrix but instead of dodging fast-moving things he can catch them. Peg a ball at him from ten feet away, he'll catch it.   We played that game for hours when he was little, with a beanbag.

"peg a ball" I had to look it up, I guessed it meant "to throw" (easy enough) but I didn't understand how "peg" fitted in. Baseball phrase... is the expression also used outside of that sport?

@MarilouA  To peg a ball is to throw it hard, with speed, in a straight line.  The very opposite of  lob, where the ball travels in an obvious parabola and is often thrown underhand.  You can get pegged with a snowball but I can't think of any other sport where the verb is used with this meaning.

We sometimes encounter this when a person is going through
some text with
another person.  Due to the size of the desk, the two have to sit opposite each
other.

The book is upside-down, please turn it right-side-up.

sounds complicated.   I'd just say You're reading the book upside-down; please turn it around.
Edit
or
You're reading the book the wrong way round; please turn it the right way round (or 'up').
The book is the wrong way round for you; please turn it the right way round (or 'up').

I'd say 'please turn it (or put it) the right way up.'

I would say "The book is the wrong way round for me".  As Seowjooheng says, it would be the right way round for someone sitting opposite to me. Sometimes when I've been 'signing in' to some event where a person seated at a desk had had a list of names, I've been able to pick out my name more quickly than they could because I can 'read upside down'. (The letters are upside down; the list is the right way round for the person using it.)

Thanks, @Kate Bunting and
Michael Harvey. I've  edited my answer.
